# AsPerRequestSingleton() registration using Factory method with TinyIOC Container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, tinyioc

I'm looking into TinyIOC for ASP.NET MVC application.

What I'm trying to do is register some interface as singleton per request using factory method.

```
var container = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current;
container.Register<IGlobal>((c, n) => FactoryMethod()).AsPerRequestSingleton();
```

The code above gives me `Cannot convert current registration of TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+DelegateFactory to singleton`. Is there a way to implement this with TinyIOC without using ChildContainers?

Comment: Probably not. Not being able to use factory methods for singleton lifestyles is one of the shortcomings of TinyIoC.

Comment: That's a pity. Btw, could you please post this as an answer, so I could accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, forgot that....

So, TinyIoC currently (as of 1.2) can't register for singleton lifestyles when using factory methods.

Oh, and as you mention child containers - be careful with those, they're broken as well.

Comment: A link to the issue?

Comment: I don't know if one exists. I never bothered to file TinyIoC issues, because at the time, the project appeared all but dead, and issues and pull requests were piling up without even a response.